# Asymptotic expansion of ratio of gamma function

Tags: complex-analysis, approximation, gamma-function

This may be simple problem but I'm stuck.

I have to find at least three terms of asymptotic expansion of

$$\frac{\Gamma(z+\alpha)}{\Gamma(z+\beta)}$$ I know it behave as $z^{\alpha-\beta}$. However, I am in need off all expansion. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend working with the logarithms using Stirling's series up to the $1/z^2$ term, if that's permissible. An exponentiation should then get you to the formula you require.

Comment: Not sure what you mean with *I am in need off all expansion*, but at 
http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.11#iii you find more terms of the asymptotic expansion.